# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 i cant find error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I cant see why this wont execute:

```
use dbstudents;

INSERT INTO `student` VALUES 

(1,'Ricky','House','rickyhouse@gmail.com'),
(2,'Leo','Graham','leograham@gmail.com'),
(3,'Spencer','Hudson','sepncerhudson@gmail.com'),
(4,'Tucker','Burke','tuckerburke@gmail.com'),
(5,'Korbin','Cruz','korbincruz@gmail.com');
```

Full sql:

```
    CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `dbstudents`;
USE `dbstudents`;


SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student_detail`;

CREATE TABLE `student_detail` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `phone_number` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `favourite_language` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`;

CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_detail_id` int (11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `FK_DETAIL_idx` (`student_detail_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DETAIL` FOREIGN KEY (`student_detail_id`) REFERENCES `student_detail` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I just cant find where the error is, tried to type it all again but nothing has changed, any suggestions? I really dont know

Comment: Show us the table definition.

Comment: You've set the id column to auto increment but in the insert statement you're setting an id value. Try removing it and specifying `,null` for the student detail id. or give it an actual id. Maybe even just write the full sql instead of short hand and specify the column names. `insert into `student` (<list of columns>) VALUES ()

Comment: so my statement for one student will be `('Ricky','House','rickyhouse@gmail.com')`

Answer (score 1):

You eed to define the  values that you want tio enter, the auto incrment, doesn't need to be added.

so do simething like

```
INSERT INTO `student` (`first_name`,`last_name`,`email`) VALUES 

('Ricky','House','rickyhouse@gmail.com'),
('Leo','Graham','leograham@gmail.com'),
('Spencer','Hudson','sepncerhudson@gmail.com'),
('Tucker','Burke','tuckerburke@gmail.com'),
('Korbin','Cruz','korbincruz@gmail.com');
```